# Compare date and set status

Tags: mysql

In my db, I need create some "event", because I want to know, if column validTo (DATETIME) is out of date - when it is, column status will change to 1.

what is best way to do that?

I am not sure, if I can do it via triggers or events. Or is there some better way? Also I do not want overload my db.

This task should be called per 5 minutes.

Thanks for hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about calling some process to do this.  Just include the date/time when the event expires and compare it to the current time.  You can encapsulate this logic in a view, and then get the information whenever you use the view:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*,
           (now() <= t.ValidTo) as IsValidFlag
    from table t;
```